# Gekko: @error: Connection Variable A Not Found

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have written the below code (a generalized version) in Gekko, whose model generated matches the original model exactly. however, it is not giving the proper solution. Whereas, when I do not use an array of variables and instead write the equations manually, it works perfectly fine.

In this code, bwm is a square matrix from where the values are being extracted only from the upper triangular matrix. [This is an image of the bwm here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVUfX.png)

```
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()

print('--------- Follow local path to view files --------------')
print(m.path)               # show source file path
m.open_folder()
print('-'*56)

w = m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0,ub=3)

p = m.Array(m.Var,7) #count
m.free(p)

a = np.triu(bwm)

d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    d[i] = a[i]

k = 0
n = 0
while(n!=7):
    for (k,v) in d.items():
        #print(v)
        for s in range(len(v)):
            if v[s]==1 or v[s]==0:
                continue
  
            if type(v[s]) == tuple:
                m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n] == m.log(d[k][s][0]))
                m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n+1] == m.log(d[k][s][1]))
                n+=2
            
            if type(v[s]) != tuple:
                m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n] == m.log(d[k][s]))
                n+=1        
     
m.Equation(m.log(np.prod(w)) == 0)
m.Minimize(np.sum(p**2))
m.solve()
print('w: ', w)  

print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

The error says:

```
Exception:  @error: Connection Variable A Not Found
Error: connection failed
\[0\] = calculated
unable to locate variable
\[0\]
creating file connect_error.t0 to display valid variable names
STOPPING. . .
```

I do not understand what connections mean here. When I try writing it individually, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `m.free()` function operates on an individual `gekko` variable and not an array. In this case, it isn't needed for the application. Here is a complete script that solves successfully with the `bwm` values.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

bwm = [[1, (3,1), 0.33, 8],
       [(0.33,1),1,0.11,8],
       [3,9,1,2],
       [0.12,0.12,0.5,1.0]]

print('--------- Follow local path to view files --------------')
print(m.path)               # show source file path
#m.open_folder()
print('-'*56)

w = m.Array(m.Var,4,lb=0,ub=3)

p = m.Array(m.Var,11) #count
#m.free(p)

#a = np.triu(bwm)
# zero the lower values outside upper tri-diagonal 
a =   [[1,      (3,1), 0.33, 8],
       [(0.33,1),1   , 0.11, 8],
       [0,       9,    1,    2],
       [0,       0,  0.5, 1]]

d = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    d[i] = a[i]
print(d)

k = 0
n = 0
for (k,v) in d.items():
    for s in range(len(v)):
        if v[s]==1 or v[s]==0:
            continue

        if type(v[s]) == tuple:
            m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n] == m.log(d[k][s][0]))
            m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n+1] == m.log(d[k][s][1]))
            n+=2
        
        if type(v[s]) != tuple:
            m.Equation(m.log(w[k])- m.log(w[s]) + p[n] == m.log(d[k][s]))
            n+=1        
     
m.Equation(m.log(np.prod(w)) == 0)
m.Minimize(np.sum(p**2))
m.solve()
print('w: ', w)  

print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

The length of `p` is increased to `11` to accommodate all of the non-zeros off-diagonal values in the upper triangular matrix.